# How can I separate out dependencies from requirements.txt?

Tags: python, dependencies, pip, maintainability

I am maintaining a `requirements.txt` file for my Python project, including version numbers and hashes for each package. (This is so I can install with `pip install --no-deps --require-hashes`.)

Some packages in the list are my actual requirements (for example, `Sphinx`) while others are just dependencies of those requirements (for example, everything else you get when you `pip install Sphinx`).

I want to maintain this list of requirements separately from those dependencies. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment I have simply split my requirements into two files (see below, simplified for readability). But I am not sure how maintainable this will be (false retentions, handling dependency updates...).

**requirements.txt**

```
# these are my actual requirements
-r dependencies.txt
Sphinx
```

**dependencies.txt**

```
# these are the dependencies of my actual requirements
alabaster
Babel
certifi
chardet
docutils
idna
imagesize
Jinja2
MarkupSafe
Pygments
pytz
requests
six
snowballstemmer
sphinxcontrib-websupport
urllib3
```